# rvest: how to download more than 100 rows

Tags: r, rvest

I want to download the salaries of hockey players from
https://www.spotrac.com/nhl/rankings/

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.spotrac.com/nhl/rankings/cash/"
df <- html_table(html_nodes(read_html(url), "table")[[1]], header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
df
```

I can download only 100 rows, although there are almost 1000 in total in the table. The code on the page shows a total of 100 rows.
Where to find and how to download the rest?
Thanks for any idea 
* i can do a filter on command and download in parts, but this is not comfortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done

```
    library(rvest)
    team = c('anaheim-ducks' , 'arizona-coyotes', 'boston-bruins', 'buffalo-sabres',
        'calgary-flames', 'carolina-hurricanes', 'chicago-blackhawks', 
        'colorado-avalanche','columbus-blue-jackets', 'dallas-stars', 
        'detroit-red-wings', 'edmonton-oilers', 'florida-panthers', 
        'los-angeles-kings', 'minnesota-wild', 'montreal-canadiens',
        'nashville-predators', 'new-jersey-devils', 'new-york-islanders', 'new-york-rangers',
        'ottawa-senators', 'philadelphia-flyers', 'pittsburgh-penguins',
        'san-jose-sharks', 'st-louis-blues', 'tampa-bay-lightning', 
        'toronto-maple-leafs','vancouver-canucks', 'vegas-golden-knights',
        'washington-capitals','winnipeg-jets')

y  <- NULL;
for(i in team) {
                k=html_table(html_nodes(read_html(paste0('https://www.spotrac.com/nhl/rankings/cash/',i,'/')), "table")[[1]], header = TRUE)
k$team = i
y <- rbind(y, k)
                }
y
```